# How can I print strings in a list by the number in a different list, on different lines depending on a third list?

Tags: python

For example, given:

```
On_A_Line = [2,2,3]

Lengths_Of_Lines = [5,2,4,3,2,3,2]

Characters = ['a','t','i','e','u','w','x']
```

I want it to print:

```
aaaaatt    
iiiieee    
uuwwwxx
```

So far I have tried:

```
iteration = 0

for number in Lengths_Of_Lines:

  s = Lengths_Of_Lines[iteration]*Characters[iteration]

  print(s, end = "")

  iteration += 1
```

which prints what I want without the line spacing:

```
aaaaattiiiieeeuuwwwxx
```

I just don't have the python knowledge to know what to do from there.

Comment: You're not using the `On_A_Line` list.

Comment: Perhaps `On_A_Line` refers to how many *distinct* letters from `Characters` appear per line, not how many appear after repetition?

Comment: true, id used it in testing but the example I gave was the closest id got to it working so I included that

Comment: Variable names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to loop over the `On_A_Line` list. This tells you have many iterations of the inner loop to perform before printing a newline.

```
iteration = 0
for count in On_A_Line:
    for _ in range(count):
        s = Lengths_Of_Lines[iteration]*Characters[iteration]
        print(s, end = "")
        iteration += 1
    print("") # Print newline
```

Comment: I tested it and it came up with an error " 'int' object is not iterable " so I made it range(count) and then it worked so thanks!

Comment: Sorry, second line should use `range(count)`

Answer (score 1):

Solution using a generator and itertools:

```py
import itertools

def repeat_across_lines(chars, repetitions, per_line):
    gen = ( c * r for c, r in zip(chars, repetitions) )
    return '\n'.join(
        ''.join(itertools.islice(gen, n))
        for n in per_line
    )
```

Example:

```py
>>> repeat_across_lines(Characters, Lengths_Of_Lines, On_A_Line)
'aaaaatt\niiiieee\nuuwwwxx'
>>> print(_)
aaaaatt
iiiieee
uuwwwxx
```

The generator `gen` yields each character repeated the appropriate number of times. These are joined together `n` at a time with [itertools.islice](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice), where `n` comes from `per_line`. Those results are then joined with newline characters. Because `gen` is a generator, the next call to `islice` yields the next `n` of them that haven't been consumed yet, rather than the first `n`.